# Sending messages with MPI with three threads with ISend and IRecv

Tags: c, mpi

I am trying to generate a derivative matrix in parrallel. I have the whole heat equation solver working with two threads, but now I am trying to find out how to send the bottom row to the rec2 of the next rank, and the top row to the rec1 of the previous rank. I tried fooling around with the numbers in the request matrix, but nothing worked. For some reason, I was told that with iSend the two different receives are of the same request.

Any suggestions to fix this or help me understand this better would be great.

```
  double** change = alloc(sizeX,sizeY); 
  double*    rec1;
  double*    rec2;
  int rank,size;
  MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);
  MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &size);
  MPI_Request req[4];


  if(rank != 0)
  {
    rec1 = calloc(sizeY,sizeof(double));
  }
  if(rank != size-1)
  {
    rec2 = calloc(sizeY,sizeof(double));
  }

  if ( rank == 0 )
  {
    MPI_Irecv(rec2, sizeY, MPI_DOUBLE, rank+1, 1244, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &req[1]);
    MPI_Isend(u[sizeX-1], sizeY, MPI_DOUBLE, rank+1, 1244, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &req[0]);
  }
  else if ( rank == size-1 )
  {
    MPI_Irecv(rec1, sizeY, MPI_DOUBLE, rank - 1, 1244, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &req[2]);
    MPI_Isend(u[0], sizeY, MPI_DOUBLE, rank - 1, 1244, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &req[3]);
  }
  else if ( rank != 0 && rank != size -1)
  {
    MPI_Irecv(rec1, sizeY, MPI_DOUBLE, rank-1, 1234, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &req[1]);
    MPI_Isend(u[0], sizeY, MPI_DOUBLE, rank-1, 1234, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &req[0]);

    MPI_Irecv(rec2, sizeY, MPI_DOUBLE, rank+1, 1234, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &req[2]);
    MPI_Isend(u[sizeX-1], sizeY, MPI_DOUBLE, rank+1, 1234, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &req[3]);

  }
  // setting elements of most of the points

  int xStart = 1;
  int xBound = sizeX-1;

  for(int x = xStart; x < xBound; x++)
  { 
    for(int y = 1; y < sizeY-1; y++)
    {
      change[x][y] = fpp(u[x-1][y],u[x][y],u[x+1][y],dx)
      + fpp(u[x][y-1],u[x][y],u[x][y+1],dx);
    }
  }

  MPI_Waitall(size+1,req,MPI_STATUSES_IGNORE );
```

Comment: Watch the number of request and their start ! rank 0 and rank `size-1` handle 2 messages while others handle 4. This may cause trouble in `MPI_Waitall()`. And rank  `size-1` does not initialize req[0] and req[1] !

Comment: By threads you mean processes?  They are quiet different.

Comment: @francis is quite right - the indices and number of elements you use into your request array are inconsistent, so the waitall is doomed.  My favourite way to do this is in every posted request to pass, eg, `&req[reqcnt++]`, and at the end call `MPI_Waitall(reqcnt, req...`.

Comment: You can also simplify the code by defining, eg `left = (rank > 0? rank - 1 : MPI_PROC_NULL);` and `right = (rank < size-1? rank + 1 : MPI_PROC_NULL)`, and then just using that last elseif body and deleting the rest using `left` and `right` instead of `rank+/-1`.  The waitall as above should work, but the code will be simplified reducing duplication (a source of future errors).

Answer (score 1):

Watch the number of request and their start ! rank 0 and rank size-1 handle 2 messages while others handle 4. This may cause trouble in MPI_Waitall(). And rank size-1 does not initialize req[0] and req[1]

Using the `reqcnt` trick of @JonathanDursi :

```
 int nbreq=0;
 if(rank!=0 && size>1){
   MPI_Irecv(rec1, sizeY, MPI_DOUBLE, rank - 1, 1244, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &req[nbreq]);
   nbreq++;
   MPI_Isend(u[0], sizeY, MPI_DOUBLE, rank - 1, 1244, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &req[nbreq]);
   nbreq++;
 }
 if(rank!=size-1){
   MPI_Irecv(rec2, sizeY, MPI_DOUBLE, rank+1, 1244, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &req[nbreq]);
   nbreq++;
   MPI_Isend(u[sizeX-1], sizeY, MPI_DOUBLE, rank+1, 1244, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &req[nbreq]);
   nbreq++;
 }
 ...
 MPI_Waitall(nbreq,req,MPI_STATUSES_IGNORE );
```